# Decoding escaped characters

Tags: python, unicode, decode

I'm trying to convert **string1** so it would give the output as what's on **string2**

```
string1 = "<value>UK LONDON 8CS Flr01 Rm1\\xc4\\x9f</value>"

string2 = "<value>UK LONDON 8CS Flr01 Rm1ğ</value>"
```

I'm using plone with limited options, lets assume I cannot import any external libraries.

When I tried to use .decode( 'unicode-escape') it returns following string

```
print string1.decode( 'unicode-escape' )  # prints <value>UK LONDON 8CS Flr01 Rm1Ä</value>
```

Note that it takes Ä by converting first part of the unicode **( \xc4 )**

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`string-escape`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings) encoding instead of `unicode-escape`:

```
>>> print string1.decode('string-escape')
<value>UK LONDON 8CS Flr01 Rm1ğ</value>
```

or use decode it using `unicode-escape`, then encode it using `latin1` encoding:

```
>>> print string1.decode('unicode-escape').encode('latin1')
<value>UK LONDON 8CS Flr01 Rm1ğ</value>
```

**NOTE** `string-escape` is only available in Python 2.x.

Comment: What about on Python 3.x, Is there any way I can convert ?

Comment: @user3322418, You need to encode the string to bytes first in Python 3.x: `import sys; sys.stdout.buffer.write(string1.encode().decode('unicode-escape').encode('latin1'))`

Comment: @user3322418, You can pass bytes object to `print` function in Python 3.x. But it will not give you what you want. That's why I used `sys.stdout.buffer.write` in the previous comment.

Comment: @user3322418, See [`sys.stdout` in Python  3.x documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdout): To write or read binary data from/to the standard streams, use the underlying binary buffer. ....